# The size of the smallest subgroup of $Z_{157}$ containing 4 and 22

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

My logic is this: Since $4(84)\equiv22\bmod157$, the smallest subgroup is generated by $<4>$ and that $4(118)\equiv1\bmod157$, the size of the smallest subgroup is 118.

However, this answer is incorrect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe, the question is in the framework of the multiplicative group $Z_{157}^{*}$...

Answer (score 2):

157 is a prime number, so $Z_{157}$ is simple. Its only subgroups are the trivial group and $Z_{157}$ itself, so the answer must be $Z_{157}$.

For any subgroup $H$ of any finite group $G$, the order of $H$ must divide the order of $G$. Using this we can easily see that 118 cannot be the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

What is the size of $Z_{157}$? Obviously 157. 157 is a prime number. What does Lagrange's theorem say about order of subgroups?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there: 
From $4(118)\equiv1\bmod157$ you get that the subgroup generated by $4$ contains $1$ and so is the whole group.